# systemd : changing locale without rebooting

Tags: debian, systemd, services, locale, localectl

On a Debian Stretch system, when reconfiguring locales (`dpkg-reconfigure locales` as well as using `localectl`) systemd keeps running with the boot setting. Therefore services launched with `systemctl` keep on using the old (boot time) locale.

I tried `systemctl daemon-reload` and `daemon-reexec` as well. Nothing does.

Is there any alternative to either rebooting or modifying the unit files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# systemctl show-environment
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
# systemctl set-environment LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# systemctl show-environment
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Appears to be doing the job, also for the services run by systemd (requires them to be restarted, obviously).